# Clarification on related tags for a tag returned by API

Tags: support, api, documentation

I was assuming that the related tags API call, returns **all the tags that co-occur with the input tag**. But a closer look at the API documentation indicate the following:

> Returns the tags that are **most related** to those in {tags}.

What is meant by most related? From the requests that I have tried for a few tags, it seems to return at most top 60 co-occurrence tags with decreasing count of questions in which the tags co-occur. Is this correct? May be the documentation could be improved to make this clear.

Comment: "I didn't look closely at the API documentation  [...] May be the documentation could be improved" These two statements don't make a lot of sense to me together.

Comment: *"I was assuming that the related tags API call, returns all the tags that co-occur with the input tag."* Given the pure number of questions on Stack Overflow and the sometimes shaky tagging applied by new users I doubt that a strict implementation of "all" would be useful.

Comment: I am not asking to change the API to return all the related tags. What will be more useful is an API for returning all **tag combinations** that have been used. Even that will not help if we don't know how good the tags are or how well the tagging has been done, as you have rightly pointed out. Only option is to get all the questions with the tags & do some analysis on them with the Q&A text.Tagging could be improved by at least having some guidelines.I have seen questions tagged with javascript when it does not address the language but some javascript framework.